# How to take input from three different txt files in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to take input from three different `.txt` files. 
Like let's say I compile my program in command line with the command:

```
g++ -o mainOb main.cpp
```

After this, I want to give three `.txt` files as a form of stdin. I can easily do this for one file with the command:

```
./mainOb < inputNumber1.txt
```

What I want to do is:

```
./mainOb < inputNumber1.txt inputNumber2.txt inputNumber3.txt
```

When I do this, the first input txt file is handled properly but I don't know how to go about processing the next two input files.

Comment: Is it OK to use another command? Example: `cat inputNumber1.txt inputNumber2.txt inputNumber3.txt | ./mainOb`

Comment: How is it related to C++?

Answer (score 2):

You want to concatenate the three files then pipe them into the program.

i.e.

```
cat inputNumber1.txt inputNumber2.txt inputNumber3.txt | ./mainOb
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way will be to restructure your code to use 3 files.
You can use fstream like here, I open 2 files you can easily get 3 or more if you'd like this way!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
fstream file1,file2;

file1.open(argv[1]);
file2.open(argv[2]);

string first_line;
string second_line;

file1 >> first_line;
file2 >> second_line;

cout << "File one has " << first_line << endl;
cout << "File two has " << second_line << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you run it as ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: Would it be better to make it more general and enable the program to use any number of files?

Comment: well I've never thought of that, you could make a vector<fstream> objects and use it to open access the files. If you need an example I can come up with one!
Number of files can be found out by argc

Comment: You do not need `vector<fstream>`. Just open the files one by one

Comment: You could also add code to check that the files have been opened

Comment: yeah, I didnt care about sanity for this tiny example. but you're right